# Why do many ultrasonic sensors have specific frequencies (48 kHz & 58 kHz)?

Tags: sensor, frequency, ultrasound

I am working in the automotive industry and I found that many of the ultrasonic sensors on the market (sonars) have specific frequencies, namely 48 kHz and 58 kHz. (Not that other frequencies are nonexistent, of course) Why is this so? I can’t seem to come up with a reasonable explanation. Thank you.

Edit:
I did a Google Search
Ultrasonic Sensor Frequeny "xxxkHz" 
where xxx is some integer, and they returned the following count of results:

Freq  # of hits
46kHz 2040
47kHz 3120
48kHz 10600
49kHz 849
50kHz 277000
56kHz 1950
57kHz 696
58kHz 15900
59kHz 703
60kHz 84100
There are peaks in 50 kHz & 60 kHz, because they are multiples of 10 kHz. The peak in 48 kHz & 58 kHz is not as pronounced as I had expected, so this may be just by accident.

Answer (score 2):

The frequency is specific to the sensor because they are designed to have a mechanical resonance at that frequency. Similarly, audio transducers often have a specific frequency at which they are loudest (eg. 2kHz).

As to the choice of frequency, attenuation goes up with frequency (bad) as ability to discriminate distance (and minimum distance for a given Q) improves (good). Ambient noise is less of an issue at relatively high frequencies. Having the frequency well above the range of human hearing makes it less annoying. So it's a trade-off.

Early applications of ultrasonic ranging and communication tended to use 38-50kHz (eg. Polaroid SX-70 sonar autofocus and Zenith TV remote controls).

When air and distance are not concerns, much higher frequency ultrasound is used, as for medical diagnostics.

Comment: The only problem I had was Snow on my bumper made my proximity sensors went on full alarm on my 1st in winter day driving my new Mercedes SUV when I came to a slow speed and stopped. Whazzat? Doh!  they didn’t have a unique code for blocked sensors. Doh.

Answer (score 0):

Higher f gives more beam resolution but less range unless more power to compensate for 1/f losses.  so range and resolution of say 4 or 5 sensors are tradeoffs.

The optimal f is a tradeoff been maximum sensitivity in SNR terms from disturbance noises from the engine and horn and max range.

To go more than. 4 sensor bumper I think they need to boost power and f . They all have Lambertian beam properties.  (I guess, 160deg half power]

The ratio of reflections determines the echo angle of axis.  Mine is  about 0 +-/6 LED positions. For strength on  either side . if within xx deg both LEDS come on Left Right according to echo strength.

The ratio of left right changes computes angle and the number of LEDs with strength. so it is really handy for running over groceries (NOT) but it won’t pick up a foot.

Do they have side sensors yet? They have turning blind spot sensors that are likely the lower f higher range type but aperture focused.

Comment: The adaptive cruise control, blind spot and and cross traffic sensors in modern cars usually use ~70-80GHz mm-wavelength radar. There is also some camera data for lane departure warning and they’ve used dual cameras for distance sensing. Some have tried LIDAR which makes processing easy, but has other issues.

Comment: Yah I guess that was obsolete 2007 Ford technology. They now use Radar in the BLIs system

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - I think more commonly they use 24GHz at the moment although that band is discouraged as it is being phased out. The current higher frequency bad is 76-81GHz for automotive radars but the higher frequency means they are a bit more expensive. Only the lower part of that band is currently allowed in the US.

Comment: And people worry about 5G hah yet not MRI’s in high res mode

Comment: @KevinWhite https://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/33705-comprehensive-survey-of-77-79-ghz-automotive-radar-companies-sensors-and-ics  Sounds like 24GHz will be phased out by the end of next year.